Is a geometric series weighted average less than the mean average?
Suppose I have an infinite sequence $\{a_i\}_{i=1}^\infty$ where $a_i \in [0,1]$ for all $a_i$. Next let
\begin{align*}
f(n) &= \sum_{i = 1}^n\frac{1}{2^i}a_i\\
g(n) &= \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i = 1}^na_i
\end{align*}
Is it true that $f(n) \leq g(n)$ for all $n$?
I tried showing this is true via induction on $n$. Clearly, $$f(1) = \frac{1}{2}a_1 \leq a_1 = g(1)$$
So the base case holds.
For the induction step we assume $f(n) \leq g(n)$ is true for fixed $n$. Next we have
\begin{align*}
f(n+1) &= \sum_{i = 1}^{n+1}\frac{1}{2^i}a_i\\
&\leq \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i = 1}^{n}a_i + \frac{1}{2^{n+1}}a_{n+1}\\
&\leq^? \frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{i = 1}^{n}a_i + \frac{1}{n+1}a_{n+1}\\
&=\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{i = 1}^{n+1}a_i\\
&= g(n+1)
\end{align*}
I am unsure if the line marked with a $(?)$ is true or not. Could someone please check my proof?
Thanks in advance!

We start with your expression for $f(n+1)$:
$$f(n+1) = \sum_{i = 1}^{n+1}\frac{1}{2^i}a_i$$
and then you've correctly added the next term in the sequence to $f(n)$ to get:
$$f(n+1) = \sum_{i = 1}^{n}\frac{1}{2^i}a_i + \frac{1}{2^{n+1}}a_{n+1}$$
Then you've compared this to $g(n+1)$:
$$g(n+1) = \frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{i = 1}^{n+1}a_i$$
Your uncertainty lies in whether the transition
$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i = 1}^{n}a_i + \frac{1}{2^{n+1}}a_{n+1} \leq \frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{i = 1}^{n}a_i + \frac{1}{n+1}a_{n+1}$$
is valid.
To check this, let's break down the right-hand side of the inequality and compare the terms individually.

For the first part , $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i = 1}^{n}a_i$ is becoming $\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{i = 1}^{n}a_i$ in your step. Since $\frac{1}{n} > \frac{1}{n+1}$, this transition means that the average is being spread over a larger $n+1$ rather than $n$, effectively reducing the value of the sum part, which is in line with our expectation since $f(n) \leq g(n)$ and we are looking at an average over a larger set.

2.Comparing $\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}a_{n+1}$ to $\frac{1}{n+1}a_{n+1}$ directly, notice that for all $n \geq 1$, $\frac{1}{2^{n+1}} < \frac{1}{n+1}$. This is because the function $2^{n+1}$ grows faster than $n+1$, meaning that the left-hand side of the inequality contributes a smaller amount to $f(n+1)$ than the corresponding term does to $g(n+1)$.
Hence, both parts of your inequality work towards showing that $f(n+1) \leq g(n+1)$ under the assumption that $f(n) \leq g(n)$.
$f(n+1)$ adds a smaller fraction of $a_{n+1}$ than $g(n+1)$ does (due to the properties of the exponential function in the denominator of $f(n+1)$'s additional term, and the linear growth of the denominator in $g(n+1)$'s case),  preserves the inequality by ensuring that $f(n+1)$ does not increase by a larger amount than $g(n+1)$.
################## EDIT #################################
Let's take this step by step. We have:
$$f(n+1) = f(n) + \frac{1}{2^{n+1}}a_{n+1}$$
$$g(n+1) = \frac{n}{n+1}g(n) + \frac{1}{n+1}a_{n+1}$$
From the induction hypothesis, we assume that $f(n) \leq g(n)$. Our goal is to show whether this implies $f(n+1) \leq g(n+1)$.
Let's expand $g(n+1)$:
$$g(n+1) = \frac{n}{n+1} \left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i = 1}^{n}a_i\right) + \frac{1}{n+1}a_{n+1}$$
$$g(n+1) = \frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{i = 1}^{n}a_i + \frac{1}{n+1}a_{n+1}$$
$$g(n+1) = \frac{1}{n+1}\left(\sum_{i = 1}^{n}a_i + a_{n+1}\right)$$
Now, let's compare $f(n+1)$ and $g(n+1)$. The induction step in your proof seems to assume that:
$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i = 1}^{n}a_i + \frac{1}{2^{n+1}}a_{n+1} \leq \frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{i = 1}^{n}a_i + \frac{1}{n+1}a_{n+1}$$
This would break down into two inequalities that must both hold true:

$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i = 1}^{n}a_i \leq \frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{i = 1}^{n}a_i$
$\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}a_{n+1} \leq \frac{1}{n+1}a_{n+1}$

The first inequality can be simplified to:
$$\frac{n+1}{n} \leq 1$$
This is clearly not true for any $n \geq 1$, meaning the assumption in the question that leads to the question mark is incorrect.
To correctly analyze this, we need to keep in mind that:
$$f(n+1) = f(n) + \frac{1}{2^{n+1}}a_{n+1} \leq g(n) + \frac{1}{2^{n+1}}a_{n+1}$$
The proper comparison with $g(n+1)$ would be:
$$f(n+1) \leq \frac{n}{n+1}g(n) + \frac{1}{2^{n+1}}a_{n+1}$$
And we need to check if this is less than or equal to:
$$g(n+1) = \frac{n}{n+1}g(n) + \frac{1}{n+1}a_{n+1}$$
Now, because $\frac{1}{2^{n+1}} \leq \frac{1}{n+1}$ for $n \geq 1$, it's clear that the additional term to $f(n+1)$ is less than or equal to the corresponding term in $g(n+1)$, thereby confirming that $f(n+1) \leq g(n+1)$. The induction step and the original statement hold true.

I can understand your 2nd point, but not your first. Is the decrease from $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i = 1}^na_i$ to $\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{i = 1}^na_i$ really outweighed by the increase from $\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}a_{n+1}$ to $\frac{1}{n+1}a_{n+1}$ in general?
